# $.ajax . Error function is invoked, while i am getting 200 Ok status and data as response?

Tags: java, ajax, api

```
function jsonData() {
    $.ajax({
       async: false,
       url:'http://localhost:8080/libraryapi/BookTransactionController',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function() { alert("Success"); },
      error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
});
```

}

The Status is 200 Ok and the server is also responding with the json data but it is invoking the error function?

```
Ths Json data response from browser is:
 [{"bookName":"Book","dueDate":"2015-4-8","issueDate":"2015-5-16","studentId":201},
{"bookName":"Book2","dueDate":"2015-4-8","issueDate":"2015-5-16","studentId":211}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are working in same machine, this is happening because your API server's port and API consuming application's port is different and browsers don't allow cross domain resource sharing.

The solution is implementing [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). For more info read [Mozilla Documentation on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

For your question, possible solutions are:

If your API is in Java, use:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

`*` in above line will allow access to all domains, For allowing access to specific domain only:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");
```

If your API is using PHP language, use:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

If you are using python's [Flask Microframework](http://flask.pocoo.org/), use [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)